# Difference between completer and isolate

Tags: flutter, dart

I am really confused with the difference between an isolate and a completer in Flutter. Can anyone explain it to me

Comment: I did come across this and i couldn’t understand still

Comment: Then you have to explain what you don't understand.

Comment: okay. i understand isolates now. what i want to know is. does completer also run on a different thread?

Comment: That is also answered on the link I posted.